# how do i calculate agreement in a poll?

Tags: javascript, statistics

I am not at all good with statistics which also doesn't help me looking for a proper answer.
I am trying to calculate an agreement value in a vote between multiple people. And people can vote in numbers (1, 2, 3, 5, etc).
What would be a nice way to have like a percentage of agreement in each voting round?
If there's a javascript library, it would be welcome.

edit:

I don't have any code yet. All I am asking is if there's a formula that given, lets say, a dictionary where key is the voted item, and the value is the number of votes, I would get an agreement rating.
so lets say:

```
const votesA = { one: 4, two: 2, three: 1, five: 0}
const votesB = { one: 7, two: 0, three: 0, five: 0}
```

then I would like to know based on that, how can I calculate the agreement scale.

So for votesB I would expect the agreement to be 100%.
But for the votesA I have no idea how to calculate, although I would expect something larger, since more than half the group voted on the same answer.
I am just not at all familiar with a lot of stats concepts, so I don't know where to search for that answer.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+poll+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: I think that we need a lot more information about this one

Comment: sorry guys, I added more explanation. I hope that is ok